# list/tuple of string in terraform not working in the IAM policy resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a list of objects in an S3 bucket defined in locals:

```
locals {
    s3_bucket_object_list = [
        "Completed/",
        "Error/",
        "Processing/",
        "Temp/"
    ]
    s3_bucket_object_list_arn = [ for object in local.s3_bucket_object_list: "arn:aws:s3:::${var.bucket_name}/${object}*" ]
}
```

Here I needed the `"arn:aws:s3:::"` in the list to be used later in the IAM policy resource specification, so I used the **`for`** expression. And then I just used the local *`s3_bucket_object_list_arn`* in the following policy:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "s3" {
    name = "s3-policy"

    policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "${local.s3_bucket_object_list_arn}"
    }
    ]
}
EOF
}
```

I got the following error:

> local.s3_bucket_object_list_arn is a tuple with # elements. Cannot
> include the value in a string template: String required.

As far as I know, if it's a single resource, the resource should be enclosed with double quotes so that it's a string, but for multiple resources, lists can be used here, with each element being string. So I wonder why it's not working here in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `local.s3_bucket_object_list_arn` is a list. To use it in an IAM policy, you need to convert it to **valid json list**. For this, [jsonencode](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/jsonencode.html) can be used:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "s3" {
    name = "s3-policy"

    policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": ${jsonencode(local.s3_bucket_object_list_arn)}
    }
    ]
}
EOF
}
```

Comment: The jsonencode could be done in the locals as well.